# Make a SQL Server JOIN on a specific condition

Tags: sql-server

I am a complete beginner with SQL, and I have to turn a query like this one:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM  db1
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT col1, col2 FROM db2 WHERE some_conditions) AS query1
  ON (query1.col1 = col2)
```

Into a query like this one:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM db1
if col1 = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT col1, col2 FROM db2 WHERE some_conditions) AS query1
  ON (query1.col1 = col2) 
else
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT col1, col2 FROM db2 WHERE some_other_conditions) AS query1
  ON (query1.col1 = col2)
```

But the latter obviously doesn't work in SQL Server. What would be the proper format for a query like this?

Comment: The SELECT requires nothing from query1 as far as I can tell, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I tried to simplified the query but maybe it doesn't mean much right now, but what I need to do is to have a different sub-query depending on the value of some column in the main query...

Comment: it might be easier to help you if you shouwed the data structure and some sample data and sample results wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a complex `on` clause:

```
select  *
from    db1
left join
        db2
on      db1.col1 = db2.col2
        and (
            (db1.col1 = 1 and some_conditions)
            or (db1.col1 <> 1 and some_other_conditions)
        )
```

Using `or`, you can use one codition set in one case, and another condition set in another case.